# How to Add RSS feed in Hexo blog

Tags: hexo

How to Add RSS (Rich Site Summary) feed in Hexo blog?

Is there any inbuilt `plugin` available for adding an `RSS` feed to the blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hexo-generator-feed` plugin can be used for adding RRS feeds to hexo blog.  https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-generator-feed